# Keep Chrome's device mode open, even after closing DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Firefox allows you to close the console while keeping their device mode open. Is there a way to do this with Chrome's DevTools?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Device Mode closes when DevTools closes. So strictly speaking, no. This is not possible.

A possible workaround is to undock DevTools by opening the [Command Menu](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ui#command-menu) and then typing `Undock` and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the command. DevTools undocks to a separate window, which you can then minimize.

Comment: +1 for this workaround. You can also undock the DevTools (at least in Opera) by clicking the three vertical dots in the upper right corner (to the left of the x button) and selecting one of the options labeled "Dock side", specifically the option all the way to the right, titled "Undock into separate window"